# Ruby on rails If image in database exist, else blank image will display

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```
 <% @admin_spot.each do |resort| %>
            <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4 thumbnailrow1">
                    <div class="thumbnail">

                  <% if File.exist?(Rails.root + @admin_spot.resort_image.path) %>
                            <%= image_tag resort.photo.url %> 
                    <% else %>
                    <%= image_tag assets_image_blank.jpeg%>
                   <% end %>
                      <div class="caption">
                        <h3><%= resort.name %></h3>
                        <p><%= resort.address%></p>

                         <p><%=link_to "Read More +", admin_resort_detail_path(resort.id), :class=>"btn btn-primary"%></p>
                      </div>
                   </div>
           </div>
<% end %>
```

I have a problem to display image from database. If the image in the database exist,image will display..if not, other image will display.Please help me with this..

Comment: what is the current output ? does it display any of the image?

Comment: current output is error undefined method `resort_image' for #<Admin::Spot::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x269f538>

Comment: try like this `if resort.photo? then show photo; else show default;`

Comment: `assets_image_blank.jpeg` - it's an object? cause if not it should be in quotes i guess. `"assets_image_blank.jpeg"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
<% if  resort.photo.present? %>
    <%= image_tag resort.photo.url %> 
<% else %>
   <%= image_tag 'blank.jpg'%>
<% end %>
```

**Make sure your images are there and also see that their generated path is valid?**